# Where from i can get PKCS#11 library?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pkcs#11

What library do I need in order to use all PKCS#11 functions (like C_INITIALIZE, C_FINALIZE).
I've searched a lot but did not find anything. 
Also my project must be in WINDOWS, Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Library implementing PKCS#11 API is usually provided by the vendor of your cryptographic device (smartcard, token, HSM...). Alternatively you can also use pure software PKCS#11 implementation such as [SoftHSM](https://github.com/disig/SoftHSM2-for-Windows).